# incorrect-gcm-sender-id google firebase cloud messaging

Tags: javascript, firebase-cloud-messaging

Using `messaging.getToken()` triggers error in the console:

> messaging/incorrect-gcm-sender-id Please change your web app manifest's

But when I removing `messaging.getToken()` instruction, the error goes by.

Comment: Formatted, fixed grammar

Comment: Same problem, Solved when manifest file name is exactly `manifest.json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use single quotes for the key and value. I had the same issue but this worked for me. something like: `'gcm_sender_id': '103953800507'`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `"gcm_sender_id": "103953800507"` to the manifest.json file as showed in the documentation:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#configure_the_browser_to_receive_messages

Note that the value is fixed you don't have to change it with your project specific sender id